# Python: How to group a List or an Array with numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

im stuck.

i have a huge dataframe that looks like this:

```
| Index| Field|
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1| A|
| 1| B|
| 1| C|
| 2| A|
| 2| C|
| 3| A|
| 3| B|
```

At first i was grouping the Index and concatenated the column "field"
with pandas and the groupby command.

Now my dataframe looks like this:

```
| Index| Field|
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1| [A, B, C]
| 2| [B, C] 
| 3| [A, B]
```

The next step is, that i want to count, how many times [A, B, C] exist in the whole dataset. The solution should be like this:

```
 | Field | Counts|
| -------- | -------------- |
| [A, B, C]| 222
| [B, C] | 530 
| [A, B] | 400
```

because i put it in an list (or np array), i don't know how to achieve the next output. Because i now have an list / array. i can not do another pd.groupby or im to blind to see.

can anybody give some hint or has an solution how to solve this?

thanks!

edit: sorry for the bad editing, stackoverflow didn't let me use the table formatting without saying this is some code

Comment: Your counts do not make sense based on your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `tuple` not `list` , then we can do `value_counts`

```
s = df.groupby('Index')['Field'].agg(tuple)
s.value_counts()
Out[642]: 
(A, B)       1
(A, B, C)    1
(A, C)       1
Name: Field, dtype: int64
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!